# How do I create a regex to to match a number of words where the total length is at least n?

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract telephone word numbers from free text.
The general format of the word number is '0800' followed by at least 6 alphanumeric characters.
If there is more than one word required to get at least 6 alphanumeric charaters then return the full words.

examples I have:
'PH 0800 OASIS CLEARWATER' - return '0800 OASIS CLEARWATER'
'Freephone  0800 RaceRock TM' - return '0800 RaceRock'
'Phone: 0800 7 5555 7' - return '0800 7 5555 7'

I am using oracle 10.2.0.3 (10g)

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex should work:

```
(0800(\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]){6}[a-zA-Z0-9]*)
```

It first matches 0800, then 6 alfanumeric characters, before each character you can have a number of spaces. After the sixth character you match additional characters, to get the whole word.

Be sure *not* to use `^` or `$` as you obviously want it to be possible to have strings in front of it, and after it.

Comment: markijbema - some errors in the expr you posted and have managed to rewrite it and get most of my test cases working  0800\s*([[:alnum:]-\s]{3,6})[[:alnum:]-]*

Comment: @user639494 it would be sympathetic to edit your changes into my answer. That way, if someone finds this page from google, they will presented with a correct solution. Also, I'd appreciate it if you would accept my answer, if you think it answered your question.

Comment: ones that are now failing are: "0800 7665 4 8 Any size or Shape<T025 751 263>" returns only "0800 7665 4" want "0800 7665 4 8"  AND "FREE PHONE 0800 POOL 4 U" returns "0800 POOL 4" want "0800 POOL 4 U"

Comment: I'm actually pretty sure that your solution won't solve the problem you have. What went wrong with the solution I suggested?

Comment: My apologies, there were some more typo's. I fixed the answer, does it work for you know?

Comment: Thanks for your edit, in trying to fix the error in the initial answer I must have made a mistake.  with a minor edit I now have nmy solution. (0800(\s*[a-zA-Z0-9-]){6}[a-zA-Z0-9-]*)  added the '-' character to both groups

Comment: Why do you want to match the - char? Two things: you should always put that one up front. Secondly, - is like a spacing right? You can't actually dial that on the phone, so i think you want to bundle it with the \s instead of with the letters. Test this string "0800 AAA AA - BBB" You would want it to include the B's, right? But your solution doesn't.

Comment: You are right in the "0800 AAA AA - BBB" case.  Adding '-' (and '.' as we are dealing with user entered unvalidated free text...) to the first group with the '\s' works a treat '(0800([[:blank:]-\.]*[[:alnum:]]){5,6}[[:alnum:]]*)'  Ive used the POSIX group [:blank:] as when I moved the expression into oracle it would not match using [\s-\.]